# выбрать структуру баз данных

Tags: mysql

задача в примитивном виде:
есть человек, для него хранится name и email. при этом могут добавиться другие данные, например "телефон". записей будет много: около 10 миллионов.

для структуры есть 2 варианта:

1 вариант:

таблица полей field (список полей: перечисляются имя, телефон, etc),

таблица значений values (список значений полей, item_id указывает на связующий элемент, field_id указывает на поле, value - значение)

таблица записей item (связующий элемент для полей, что бы соотносить их значения к "карточке" человека)

в этом случае для одной записи item будет создано (1*количество полей) записей в values, при большом количестве полей таблица values будет разрастаться очень быстро.

2 вариант:

делаем для каждого поля свою таблицу, сохраняя данные о динамически созданных таблицах. получим такую же структуру, но без "разрастания" одной таблицы.

какой вариант лучше выбрать, что ещё можно учесть?

Comment: Типичный EAV. Вариант 1. Вариант 2 следует исключить просто потому, что структура БД не должна зависеть от данных.

Comment: Лучше за ранние, предположить все варианты развития событий, ой вариант архитектура БД

Comment: Учесть нужно как вы будете с этими данными работать (добавление, изменение, считывание)

Answer (score 0):

для примера:

```
CREATE TABLE testik.human (
  human_id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  floor BIT(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (human_id)
)

CREATE TABLE testik.email (
  email_id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email_address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  human_id INT(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (email_id, email_address)
)

ALTER TABLE testik.email 
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_email_id FOREIGN KEY (human_id)
    REFERENCES testik.human(human_id);

CREATE TABLE testik.phone (
  phone_id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  number_phone VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  numan_id INT(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (phone_id)
)

ALTER TABLE testik.phone 
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_phone_id FOREIGN KEY (numan_id)
    REFERENCES testik.human(human_id);
```